custom post type post is not displayed on website
I have a custom post type and I have the code that loops through the CPT and displays it on the website, this post has been working and recently stopped displaying the posts on the website,
I have tried reimplementing my code but nothing seems to be working the loop seems fine to me. snippet of my code below. please help.
<div class="container">
  <?php
  $currentID = get_the_ID();
  $today = date('Ymd');
  $args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 6,
    'post_type' => 'servicesdate',
    'post__not_in' => array($currentID),
    'meta_key'  => 'date',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
    array(
            'key'       => 'date',
            'compare'   => '>',
            'value'     => $today,
        )
    )
  );
  $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
  if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
        <div>content</div>
    <?php endwhile;
  endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
  </div>


What does var_dump($the_query) say? Also, is there anything unusual in your error logs (warnings, notices, etc)?

If you can't find any apparant errors then I would suggest to rebuild the query and add each property one by one until it stops working again.

@FiddlingAway the var_dump(the_query) helped see the post listed, thank you for the hint.

The problem is that my post's event date has passed and is less than today's date. My meta_query states that the servicesdate date must be greater than today's date. I have made the rule greater than or equal to today's date and added new post to the CPT
'meta_query' => array(
   array(
        'key'       => 'date',
        'compare'   => '>=',
        'value'     => $today,
    )
 )
);

